# MSTest.TestAdapter (1.0.0-preview) does not discover tests (mstest) in VS2015 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2015, mstest, .net-core, test-runner

Inside project.json I wrote:

*"testRunner": "mstest"*

and in dependences:

*"MSTest.TestAdapter": "1.0.0-preview"*

But Test Explorer is not able to discover any tests inside.

I guessed that correct package is *"dotnet-test-mstest": "1.0.1-preview"*

But it does not work as well...

In command line *dotnet test* command runs correctly:

```
Discovering Tests ...
Executing Tests ...
Passed   AuthenticateSuccessful
============ Test Run Summary ============
Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0
Test Run Successful.
SUMMARY: Total: 1 targets, Passed: 1, Failed: 0.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found the reason and solved it... at least it looks so.

After installing Update 3 (vs2015.3.exe) I have installed KB with fixes for that update. It is vs14-kb3165756.exe, which was received as update in notifications panel of VS.

Microsoft says the following about this update:
*This is a cumulative servicing update that provides fixes to Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. These fixes address high-impact bugs that were either found by the product team or reported by the community. This update will be released on a recurring basis as new bugs are found and fixed. New fixes will be added to the previous fixes.*

After this update Test Explorer does not show any tests. BUT it can run them!
So to fix that I have just changed grouping using Group By [Type] button in Test Explorer. Now all tests are visible in Visual Studio!

***UPDATE***

Finally I have received **new** version of the same KB (vs14-kb3165756.exe)
And now all works like a charm... So question is solved.. .If you have such troubles just get the latest update.